# C# Make everything following public / private like in C++?

Tags: c#, subclass, private, public

I recently started learning C#, but I have some background in C++.
I was wondering how I would do something like

```
class employee
{
    public:
       ....
  ... methods ...
       ....

    private:
       ....
    ... private member variables ....
       ....
}
```

I tried doing this in C#, but it doesn't like the "public: ..." and "private: ..." to make everything after it either public or private.

Also, I've seen that theres this get and set thing in C#, so you don't need to do things in  the way of making a private member variable, then making a function to return that variable?

While i'm at it, how does one make subclasses in C#? In C# new classes get opened in different tabs, so I'm confused as to how I would do it.

Comment: This is really _way_ to many questions at once to be answered at Stack Overflow. It seems you would benefit more by reading a book about C#. I would also recommend reading the SO FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) and this http://bit.ly/PerfectQuestion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-c

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't make "blocks" public or private in C# as you would in C++, you'll have to add the visibility (and implementation) to each member. In C++, you'd normally do;

```
public:
  memberA();
  memberB();
private:
  memberC();
```

...and implement your members elsewhere, while in C#, you'd need to do;

```
public  memberA() { ...implement your function here... }
public  memberB() { ...implement your function here... }
private memberC() { ...implement your function here... }
```

As for properties, see them as auto implemented `set` and `get` methods which you can choose to implement yourself or have the compiler implement them. If you want to implement them yourself, you'll still need the field to store your data in, if you leave it up to the compiler, it will also generate the field.

Inheritance works exactly the same as it would if you put things in the same file (which is probably not even a good idea for bigger C++ projects). Just inherit as usual, as long as you're in the same namespace or have the namespace of the base class imported, you can just inherit seamlessly;

```
using System.Collections;  // Where IEnumerable is defined

public class MyEnumerable : IEnumerable {  // Just inherit like it 
   ...                                     // was in the same file.
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you answered this, despite the question being 'not a real question'. I had been looking at C++ code, and didn't realize that you couldn't do block settings in C#. Saved me a lot of time Googling!

Answer (score 4):

1) Access modifiers in C# are different from C++ in that you need to explicitly specify one per class member.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(v=vs.71).aspx

2) The get, set you are mentioning refer to C# Properties:

```
class User
{
    private string userName;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return this.userName; }
        set { this.userName = value; }
    }
}
```

Pls note that you can also use auto-implemented properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

3) Subclassing in C# is done like so

```
class Manager : Employee 
{
    //implementation goes here as usual
}
```

Comment: +1, but note that you don't *need* to specify accessibility explicitly; there is a default accessibility.  Any explicit accessibility modifier, of course, applies to exactly one type member (or to one type).

Comment: Yes that is totally correct. 'Internal' is the default access level for Classes and Structs if not explicitly defined. While for a class member:  "Normally, the accessibility of a member is not greater than the accessibility of the type that contains it." as can be read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Comment: The default accessibility for a class member is `private`; the quotation is saying something slightly different: if you give the member a greater accessibility than its containing class, the more restrictive accessibility of the containing class normally prevents access to the member in contexts where the class is inaccessible.  In other words, given `internal class C { public string P { get; set; } }`, `P` will not normally be visible outside the assembly.

Comment: However, with `internal class C { private string P { get; set; } }` (or `internal class C { string P { get; set; } }`, which is equivalent), `P` is not visible to code outside of class `C`.  Even if `C` were public, the default accessibility of `P` is private.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, you can't. In C# you must specify accessor for each member.
2. No you don't, it's called `Property`
3. Write it other class

```
class SomeClass
{

}
class SubClass:SomeClass {}
```

Comment: 3: That's not a subClass, that's a *nested class*.

Answer (score 3):

in C# you'll have to specify the access specifier for each method or property.
If you don't specify it takes the default access specifier.

 Default access specifier for class members are private and default for things outside a class is internal

```
class MyClass{ //MyClass will be internal
     int MyProperty {get; set;} // MyProperty will be privare
}
```