# Is it possible to create a "private" or "public" block in C# like in C++?

Tags: c#

In C++ it's possible to create a "block" of members by privacy:

```
private :
    int var1;
    char var2;
    ...

public :
    int var3;
    char var4;
    ...
```

I have tried to find examples of the same in C#, but couldn't find one. I tried to write such a block in Visual Studio, but I got an error.

Is there a similar syntax that is valid in C#?

Comment: No.  Each member has to be prefixed with an access modifier, or it resorts to the default.

Comment: I think the short answer is: No.

Comment: At present, the answer is no.

Comment: as @MikeChristensen mentioned, this is exact duplicate. Please, use search

Comment: I sometimes wonder how people decide to upvote/downvote. Is the first vote usually the setting trend? The [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312123/c-sharp-make-everything-following-public-private-like-in-c) was downvoted as much as this one was upvoted.

Comment: @ebeeb, The other question (which I didn't find before the close vote) is very messy and asks several different questions meshed together, I think this is why it got the downvotes and was closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is **no, there isn't.**
You always should write the access specifier in front of your field/method.

```
public int var1;
public char var2;
```

Note that `private` is the default specifier. It is a question of design, but I would always explicitly designate the modifier. (And even if it is just for the consistent indentation!)

Read more on [Accessibility Levels (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) at msdn.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should write access modifier before each member(property,field or method).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. You need to prefix *each* line with one of the access specifiers. If you don't, there is a default (private for members, internal for types).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, but if you want to group class members into logical groups, you can use [regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
#region Private properties

private int var1;

#endregion
```

Comment: Please don't use regions, reading such code results in continuous expanding/collapsing regions all the time...Grouping members with same access level should be just fine

Comment: Ugh, I'm glad I'm not the only one who hates regions..

Comment: Some people love regions and I find it a lot in code other developers have written. I personally don't like them either.

Comment: I did not say "you **should** use regions", just you **can**. :) I personally never use them.

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** possible. Here some other hints though:

If you'd like to achieve different accessing for reading and writing try this:

```
public int Var1 { get; private set; }
```

If your purpose is just shortening your code, this saves at least some characters.

```
private int _var1, _var2, _var3;
private char _char1, _char2;
```

Answer (score 0):

At present, the answer is no.
The intent of adding access modifiers like

```
public string name;
public string address;
```

was to make code more readable.